Retain literal type information when returning object literal from within passed function
To illustrate my issue I made a function that accepts a data and a function - that takes these data while retaining literal values, and then returns anything (literal object/number/string mostly) - when I return an object literal I want its literal values be retained, which sadly doesn't happen. Playground
First is just a version that doesn't attempt to keep any literal types, it only keeps a type from data to parameter of a passed function:
const issue = <const T, F extends (data: T) => any>
(data: T, fn: F): ReturnType<F> => {return null as any}

const lostTypeInfo = issue({prop: "literal"}, data => ({output: "out value"}))

Second is an attempt to keep the types intact, adding Ret type parameter I was hoping will get bound properly to return value, but this is not the case:
const attempt = <const T, F extends <const Ret>(data: T) => Ret>
    (data: T, fn: F): ReturnType<F> => {return null as any}

const typeError = attempt({prop: "literal"}, data => ({output: "out value"}))

I was looking here on questions/answers with an error this causes, but questions/solutions were not very universal/related to this problem, so I wonder whether there is something I can do here, output of that function must retain any object type literals, or just number/string values.

You can't do this by making it generic in the type of fn since there's no "const context" for functions that does anything useful. You could make it generic in the return type as shown in this playground link which gives the context you need. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Great, thank you very much, this solved it perfectly, I should have try to move it into fn param declaration, somehow I thought it could be made working there and tried everything except correct solution.

I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

There's no great way to ask TypeScript for a const context for a function, so if your function is generic in the type of fn, it's not necessarily going to work, especially if your generic const type parameter is constrained to a function type:
const id = <const T extends () => any>(x: T) => x;
const g = id(() => "abc")
//    ^? const g: () => string

You can't even use a const assertion on a function directly:
const f = (() => "abc") as const;
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// A 'const' assertion can only be applied to references to enum members, 
// or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
// const f: () => string

And while it was an interesting idea to make the constraint itself a generic function with a const type parameter, like F extends <const R>(t: T)=>R, since that doesn't actually mean anything different from F extends <R>(t: T)=>R (const type parameters don't constrain anything, just change contextual inference at the call site. I don't think they do anything to the implementation site).

I'd say the best way to proceed here is to make the function generic in the intended return type of fn, and make that a const type parameter:
const issue = <const T, const R>
    (data: T, fn: (data: T) => R): R => { return null as any }

const x = issue({ prop: "literal" }, data => ({ output: "out value" }))
//    ^? const x: { readonly output: "out value"; }

That works because it's the returned object literal that gets the const context, and not the function type.
Playground link to code
